# IE 11 magically crashing when doing animation with velocity.js and svg

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, internet-explorer-11, velocity.js

[the js fiddle showing the crash of ie 11 when running velocity.js to do a svg animation](http://jsbin.com/fuyagukiyu/3/edit)

just left click on the arrow with the f next to it

this only happens in IE 11, **maybe on other versions of IE too.**

Chrome works fine as it seems.

HTML

```
<html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/velocity/1.2.1/velocity.js"></script>
</head>


<body>


<style type="text/css">

body { 
  background-color:#000000
}

#box1 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  top: 330px;
  width: 257px;
  height: 62px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#box2 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 250px;
  top: 330px;
  width: 315px;
  height: 62px;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

#positionP {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  top: 330px;
}

#positionG {
  position: absolute;
  right: 250px;
  top: 330px;
}

</style>


<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function(){
 var lux = {};
 lux.isPopen = false;
 lux.isGopen = false;
    $(".doanimateP").on("click", function(){
       $(".animated").velocity("stop", true);
    if(lux.isPopen){
            $(".animated").velocity("reverse");
            lux.isPopen = false;
            return;
    }
        lux.isPopen = true;

    if(lux.isGopen){
         $(".animated2")
       .velocity("stop", true)
                    .velocity("reverse", {
          duration: "50"
          });
          lux.isGopen = false;
    }


       $(".toBeAnimatedLine1")
        .velocity({ y2: "469"},{
          duration: "2000"});
     $(".toBeAnimatedLine2")
    .velocity({ x2: "50" },{ 
      duration: "350",
      delay: "800"});
     $(".toBeAnimatedLine3")
    .velocity({ x2: "50" },{ 
      duration: "350",
      delay: "1000"});
     $(".toBeAnimatedLine4")
    .velocity({ x2: "50" },{ 
      duration: "350",
      delay: "1400"});
     $(".toBeAnimatedLine5")
    .velocity({ x2: "50" },{ 
      duration: "350",
      delay: "1900"});
     $(".tanim1")
   .velocity({opacity: 1},{
     duration: "700",
     delay: "800"});
     $(".tanim2")
   .velocity({opacity: 1},{
     duration: "700",
     delay: "1000"});
     $(".tanim3")
   .velocity({opacity: 1},{
     duration: "700",
     delay: "1400"});
     $(".tanim4")
   .velocity({opacity: 1},{
     duration: "700",
     delay: "1900"});
     $(".tanim5")
   .velocity({opacity: 1},{
     duration: "700",
     delay: "2100"});
     $(".tanim6")
   .velocity({opacity: 1},{
     duration: "700",
     delay: "2300"});
     $(".tanim7")
   .velocity({opacity: 1},{
     duration: "700",
     delay: "2500"});
     $(".tanim8")
   .velocity({opacity: 1},{
     duration: "700",
     delay: "2700"});
    });

});

</script>

<div id="box1" class="doanimateP"></div>

<div id="positionP">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   width="949.574px" height="625.847px" viewBox="0 0 949.574 625.847" enable-background="new 0 0 949.574 625.847"
   xml:space="preserve">

<g>
  <g>
    <g>
      <path fill="#C4C6C8" d="M30.5,60.993c-5.386,0-10.703-1.446-15.376-4.184c-0.455-0.266-0.608-0.853-0.342-1.308
        c0.267-0.456,0.854-0.608,1.309-0.342c4.38,2.565,9.362,3.921,14.409,3.921c5.048,0,10.03-1.356,14.408-3.922
        c0.455-0.268,1.042-0.114,1.309,0.343c0.267,0.455,0.114,1.041-0.342,1.308C41.204,59.547,35.888,60.993,30.5,60.993z"/>
      <path fill="#C4C6C8" d="M9.55,52.259c-0.245,0-0.49-0.095-0.678-0.282C3.15,46.219,0,38.592,0,30.498
        c0-8.092,3.15-15.721,8.871-21.479c0.373-0.375,0.979-0.376,1.353-0.005c0.375,0.372,0.377,0.978,0.005,1.352
        c-5.363,5.399-8.316,12.55-8.316,20.133c0,7.585,2.953,14.733,8.316,20.131c0.372,0.375,0.37,0.979-0.004,1.353
        C10.037,52.166,9.794,52.259,9.55,52.259z"/>
      <path fill="#C4C6C8" d="M15.608,5.965c-0.328,0-0.648-0.168-0.826-0.473c-0.267-0.455-0.114-1.041,0.342-1.308
        C19.797,1.446,25.114,0,30.5,0s10.703,1.446,15.376,4.185c0.456,0.267,0.608,0.853,0.341,1.308
        c-0.267,0.456-0.853,0.61-1.308,0.343C40.528,3.269,35.546,1.912,30.5,1.912c-5.047,0-10.029,1.356-14.409,3.923
        C15.938,5.924,15.772,5.965,15.608,5.965z"/>
      <path fill="#C4C6C8" d="M51.449,52.259c-0.243,0-0.487-0.093-0.674-0.277c-0.375-0.373-0.377-0.978-0.005-1.353
        c5.363-5.396,8.316-12.546,8.316-20.131c0-7.584-2.953-14.733-8.315-20.133c-0.372-0.374-0.37-0.979,0.005-1.352
        c0.373-0.373,0.979-0.371,1.352,0.005C57.849,14.777,61,22.405,61,30.498c0,8.094-3.151,15.722-8.872,21.479
        C51.941,52.164,51.695,52.259,51.449,52.259z"/>
    </g>
    <polygon fill="#FFFFFF" points="30.5,44.277 16.5,23.028 30.5,23.028 44.5,23.028     "/>
  </g>

  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 75 47.875)" fill="#FFFFFF" font-family="'AgfaRotisSansSerif'" font-size="36">f
  </text>
  <text transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 75 224.875)">
  <tspan class="tanim1 animated" style="opacity:0" x="0" y="0" fill="#FFFFFF"       font-size="36">e
  </tspan>
  <tspan class="tanim2 animated" style="opacity:0" x="0" y="86.4" fill="#FFFFFF"    font-size="36">d
  </tspan>
  <tspan class="tanim3 animated" style="opacity:0" x="0" y="172.8" fill="#FFFFFF"    font-size="36">c
  </tspan>
  <tspan class="tanim4 animated" style="opacity:0" x="0" y="252" fill="#FFFFFF"      font-size="30">b
  </tspan>
  <tspan class="tanim5 animated" style="opacity:0" x="0" y="288" fill="#FFFFFF"  font-size="30">a
  </tspan>
  <tspan class="tanim6 animated" style="opacity:0" x="0" y="324" fill="#FFFFFF"  font-size="30">z
  </tspan>
  <tspan class="tanim7 animated" style="opacity:0" x="0" y="360" fill="#FFFFFF" font-size="30">y
  </tspan>
  <tspan class="tanim8 animated" style="opacity:0" x="0" y="396" fill="#FFFFFF" font-size="30">x
  </tspan>
  </text>

  <line class="toBeAnimatedLine1 animated" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="29" y1="70" x2="29" y2="70"></line>
  <line class="toBeAnimatedLine2 animated" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="30" y1="212" x2="30" y2="212"/>
  <line class="toBeAnimatedLine3 animated" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="30" y1="298" x2="30" y2="298"/>
  <line class="toBeAnimatedLine4 animated" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="30" y1="385" x2="30" y2="385"/>
  <line class="toBeAnimatedLine5 animated" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="30" y1="468" x2="30" y2="468"/>
</g>
</svg>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I got the exact same error. 
In my code its only happens when i hover a specific div. (Don't know why)..
Have you found a solution ? Or did you find a way to debug the error ? :)

Comment: @ThomasBolander I actually worked around it. If IE I set display to none and then to block instead of the animation. I basically found out which part of the animation broke it, and didnt do that. So in my example it is the text that appears, that crashes it. So I just didnt animate the text (just display none and then block). Eventually you could have moved the text out of the svg as well. Well if you use IE, you have to live with workarounds like that because your browser sadly still sucks.

Comment: thank you very much! Haha, yeah, IE really sucks. 
The problem is that i have a lot of css animation, so it will take a while to find the animation which cause the error. 

But again.. Thanks for your reply :)